# Angularjs error : app is not defined

Tags: angularjs

I have a loginController.js,loginService.js,app.js and a view page

**app.js**

```js
var validation = angular.module('validationApp', ['ui.router','ngDialog','ngSanitize','angularSpinner']);
validation.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url : '/login',
        views: {
            "mainView": {
               controller: 'loginController',
               templateUrl: '/public/app/login/loginView.phtml'
            },
        }
    }).run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$http', function ($rootScope, $location, $http) {
    
    $rootScope.globals = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('globals')) || {};
    if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata;
    }
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {

        var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
        if (!loggedIn) {
            $location.path('/login');
        } else if (loggedIn && $location.path() == '/login') {
            $location.path('/validation');
        }
    });
    
}]);
```

**loginService.js**

```js
app.factory('loginService', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    var service = {};
    
    service.Login            = Login;
    service.SetCredentials   = SetCredentials;
    service.ClearCredentials = ClearCredentials;

    return service;
  function Login(user, callback)
    {
        var request = $http({
            method  : "post",
            url     : "/app/index/login",
            data    : {
                        userEmail: user.userEmail,
                        password: user.password
                      }
        }).success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
            callback(response);
        });
    };
```

**loginController.js**

```js
validation.controller('loginController',['$scope','$http', '$location','loginService',function($scope,$http,$location,loginService) {
   
    
        $scope.submitForm = function(user) {

        $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/index.php/home/create',
            data: {
                username:$scope.user.userName,
                password:$scope.user.password,
            },
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  }).success(function(response){
                     loginService.SetCredentials(response.userData);
                    ..............................
```

while executing my code i am getting an error like :

1.app is not defined in loginService.js

2.Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: loginServiceProvider <- loginService <- loginController

I am new in angularjs.so please help me to solve this.

Comment: replace app with validation in your loginService.js @student

Comment: @student you might want to consider not use this approach! You should better ask angular for you ngApp in each of your files, to remove the issue with a variable in the global scope. Have a look at my answer or the one of Giovani.

Comment: ok.i will try that one also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more sofisticated aproach would be to get the ngApp in each file. This removes the issues you have at the moment with not referencing the correct global variable ('don't polute the global scope' is a statement you might want to consider as well).

```
angular.module('validationApp').controller(...)
```

or

```
angular.module('validationApp').factory(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1.app is not defined in loginService.js

Exactly what it says, you're using the app variable, but it isn't defined in loginService (or in any of the other js files).

Replace the following in loginService.js

```
app.factory
```

with

```
angular.module('validationApp').factory
```

> 2.Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider Unknown provider: loginServiceProvider <- loginService <- loginController

This error is caused because of the mistake you made in loginService.js

Answer (score 0):

You should replace validation.factory instead of app.factory

Answer (score 0):

Change

**FROM**

```
app.factory('loginService', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
```

**TO**

```
validation.factory('loginService', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
```